# Javascript: Appending form input into a table upon submission

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am very new to Javascript and HTML.

I'm trying to make it so that after a user enters some information into the input form and clicks a submit button, said information appears in a table above or below the form. How can I do it without JQuery?

Here's my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = myFunction;

function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("fname");
everything.innerHTML = x.value + y.value + z.value;

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="everything">everything goes here

</div>
<p></p>

Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" >
<p></p>
Enter your age: <input type="number" id="fage" >
<p></p>
Enter your city: <input type="text" id="fcity" >
<p></p>
<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The script runs before the element is available. Move the script to right before `</body>`

Comment: or you can add event listener for loading page, like this
window.onload =  eventHandler;
function eventHandler() {
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = myFunction;
}

Comment: I'd recommend wrapping your code in an on-ready function: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do work
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have some problems in your code. First is because you try to access to element that at the moment does not exist. Second you need to get your elements.

### Wath [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/nMtcgZ48yvGmp7sLcWWo?p=preview)

You have 2 main solution.
1. Load script before closing body tag. Because dom will load first, you can have access to all dom element in your script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="everything">everything goes here

</div>
<p></p>

Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" >
<p></p>
Enter your age: <input type="number" id="fage" >
<p></p>
Enter your city: <input type="text" id="fcity" >
<p></p>
<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>


<script>

document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = myFunction;

function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("fname");
var y = document.getElementById("fage");
var z = document.getElementById("fcity");
var everythingClass = document.getElementsByClassName('everything')[0];
everythingClass.innerHTML = x.value + y.value + z.value;

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

2.Is that run script after content loaded. You will attach event handler to load event, thah will run after just dom loads.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

window.onload = eventHandler;
function eventHandler() {
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = myFunction;
}

function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("fname");
var y = document.getElementById("fage");
var z = document.getElementById("fcity");
var everythingClass = document.getElementsByClassName('everything')[0];
everythingClass.innerHTML = x.value + y.value + z.value;

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="everything">everything goes here

</div>
<p></p>

Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" >
<p></p>
Enter your age: <input type="number" id="fage" >
<p></p>
Enter your city: <input type="text" id="fcity" >
<p></p>
<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, you're absolutely right. sorry for maybe dumb question. Anyway, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You normally want to put all the JS code right before the `</body>` tag.

Also, in your current code, y and z are not defined so `x.value + y.value + z.value;` would not make any sense.

Have `var y = getElementById("fage"); var z = getElementById("fcity");`

Also, you can't refer to the div with class "everything" by just saying `everything.innerHTML`. Either just use Id (like you did for the rest of them) or do it the following way:

```
var everything = document.getElementsByClassName("everything");
everything[0].innerHTML = x.value + y.value + z.value;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: ok, yes, thank you, you're totally right, so i did everything just like you said, and now that "everything goes here" text changes into NaN. do you know why is that?